# How to get array of items using xpath in python scrapy?

Tags: python, regex, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

I need to fetch and than parse array of div's from html page. I wrote this:

```
def parse_public(self, response):
    hxs = Selector(response)
    posts = hxs.xpath("//*div[matches(@id, 'wall-28701979_\d{5}')")
    # or something like this
    # posts = hxs.findall("//div[starts-with(@id,'wall-28701979_')")
    print posts
```

The full xpath is: `//*[@id="wall-28701979_XXXXX"]/div[2]/div[1]/text()` where XXXXX - random 5 digits. So I need to get all elements like this from page. But I got an `exceptions.ValueError: Invalid XPath:` . How can I fix it? Thanks

Comment: you might want to give a sample of the markup you are trying to parse

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`matches()` is available only in `xpath 2.0`. `Scrapy` (well, `lxml`) supports only `xpath 1.0`.

You are also missing the closing `]`, but is it not really important here.

---

Instead, you can use `starts-with()`:

```
hxs.xpath("//div[starts-with(@id, 'wall-28701979_')]")
```

Or, alternatively, you can use [`re:test`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#regular-expressions). Demo from the [`scrapy shell`](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/shell.html):

```
$ cat index.html
<div>
    <div id="wall-28701979_12345">test1</div>
    <div id="wall-28701979_21231">test2</div>
    <div id="wall-28701979_31233">test3</div>
</div>
$ scrapy shell index.html
>>> response.xpath('//div[re:test(@id, "wall-28701979_\d{5}")]/text()').extract()
[u'test1', u'test2', u'test3']
```